# truncate post with gallery tag

Tags: excerpt

I have one problem I use this function for truncate posts

```
function truncate_post($amount,$quote_after=false) {
$truncate = get_the_content();
$truncate = apply_filters('the_content', $truncate);
$truncate = preg_replace('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si', '', $truncate);
$truncate = preg_replace('@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@si', '', $truncate);
$truncate = strip_tags($truncate);
$truncate = substr($truncate, 0, strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' '));
echo $truncate;
echo "...";
if ($quote_after) echo('');
}
```

but in my posts there is wordpress gallery call

```
[gallery ids="614,592,591"]
```

And now I need this truncate to not calculate this gallery tag.. because I get empty fields.. is this can be done? to truncate just text...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strip_shortcodes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes) as well. That should remove the shortcodes from the content.

A couple of notes: Your code seems to be doing some things that I don't understand. For example, you run the `the_content` filter on your content which adds markup, only to run [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) later, which removes (at least some of) that markup. [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) will strip the `<script>` and `<style>` tags too, yet you have individual [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)s for those. Also, markup left by [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php), such as `<p>` tags, will count against your character limit. And, since you are breaking on a space you may end up breaking in the middle of a tag and end up with bad markup. This:

`<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>`

May end up being ...

`<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a`

You might look into something like [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses), and certainly rethink how you deal with spaces and the broken markup that is bound to happen with this function.

Comment: yes .. correctly I get problems with this truncate.. but sometimes I need to have <p></p> in truncate so I put <p> in strip_tags .. I am not so good with this.. so I use some function from net and test it.. Its work but like you see not 100% ... Can you maybe write me here 2 types of function where I will remove shortcodes .. and second one where I will have <p> and <a> in truncate...

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is my code now...

```
function truncate_post($amount,$quote_after=false) {
    $truncate = get_the_content();
    $truncate = strip_shortcodes( $truncate );
    $truncate = strip_tags($truncate);
    $truncate = substr($truncate, 0, strrpos(substr($truncate, 0, $amount), ' '));
    echo $truncate;
    echo "...";
    if ($quote_after) echo('');
}
```